# 6 14 C:\c++\ìàññèâû\Áåçûìÿííûé1.cpp [Error] expected ';' before 's'

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int a;
     a = "Hello"s.size();
    cout << "Hello"s.size() << endl
}
```

Comment: Непонятно, что требуется. Конкретизируйте вопрос и поправьте кодировку.

Comment: А у вас компилятор какой версии? Какой стандарт поддерживает?

Comment: комментаторы, в вопросе все очевидно.

Answer (score 1):

Надо буквально чуточку поправить.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
using namespace std::string_literals; // вот эту строку
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int a;
     a = "Hello"s.size();
    cout << "Hello"s.size() << endl; // и тут точка с запятой
}
```

и конечно, компилировать с поддержкой 14 стандарта и выше.

Comment: С VC++ вполне работает и без `using namespace std::string_literals;`. Точка с запятой и в самом деле требуется :)

Comment: Прикольно, нужно будет проверить. Хотя может это `using namespace std;` шалит